# Xcode 6 exporting IPA file with locally installed provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, provisioning-profile, ipa

We're doing development for a third party where we have their `.p12` file and their production provisioning profile, but we're not added to the developer account in their Member Center.

In Xcode 5.1.1, you could export the archive, then pick the correct provisioning profile and sign the IPA file that way.

In Xcode 6, that option seems to have completely disappeared. Assuming we can't get added to their developer account, is there a way to export an IPA file with a locally installed provisioning profile (and corresponding `.p12` file)?

Answer (score 0):

I get a solution without renew the certificate:

1 - Archive the target with the appropiate Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile

2 - Right button in the created file in Organizer --> Show in Finder

3 - Right button in the xcarchive file --> Show package content

4 - There, in Finder, go to Products/Applications/

5 - Upload the file Products/Applications/appName to iTunes

6 - When the app appear in iTunes, right click on it --> Show in Finder. This is the ipa file

7 - Send this ipa through App Loader 3.0

I dont think that it is a lasting solution but do not want to delete my certificates